# coforall loops in sequence with Chapel

Tags: for-loop, chapel

I'm working on a debugger, using Chapel programming language. In my code I need to use a **`coforall`** loop, but unfortunately, I can't find a way to make the parallel iterations to be executed in sequence.

This is a part of my code:

```
coforall i in 1..n by -1 do
{  
   middle = ( ( _delta[i]._sub.length ) / 2 ) : int;   
   if( middle != 0 )
   {  
       _delta[2*i  ]._sub=_delta[i]._sub[1+middle..];
       _delta[2*i-1]._sub=_delta[i]._sub[..middle];
   }
   ...
}
```

as you can see I need the iterations of this loop to be executed in parallel and in a backward sequence.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the question. What do you mean by "executed in sequence"? Obviously you could write this portion with a 'for' loop, and that would run the iterations in order. What are you trying to achieve with `coforall` ? 'coforall' makes each of the iterations 1..n run in a separate task - why do you want that?

Comment: Missing all information what precedes `coforall ...` in your post. Would you mind to **read about how to ask the MCVE-based questions** ? StackOverflow encourages users to present a **M**inimum ( efficiency ) + **C**omplete ( self-contained ) + **V**erifiable ( ready for re-runs ) + **E**xamples ( a full example, with all details+data, to allow for re-testing ) of code, that you struggle to make work.The best next step is to learn about this Community practice+ **revise & complete your MCVE above**. Anyway, welcome in this great Community of Knowledge & become our active, contributing member.

Comment: Like @mppf, this question is not clear to me:  Why do you say you need the iterations of this loop to be executed in parallel if you need them to execute in a particular order?

Answer (score 0):

### A general rule

A code-section, that is to be executed in parallel ( a **`PAR`**-type of process scheduling ), by definition, provides no means so as to become executed on any infrastructure of hardware resources in any particular "order" ( like additionally enforcing some kind of a **`SEQ`**-type of process scheduling ), including a "reverse-(backward-stepping)-order" et al.

*As there is no such even number to be also odd at the same time,*
***there is no chance for any* `PAR` *processes-scheduling to become also* `SEQ` *at the same time.***

---

### Specific coordination tools for "ordering" task execution still possible

For indeed a special purpose, there are means -- a.k.a. synchronisation primitives -- that could provide a blocking step, so that one part of a computation has to explicitly wait until it receives a message / a value / another kind of a mutual synchronisation impulse from some other process ( a task or a part of a more complex, distributed-system computation graph ).

In all cases a carefull algorithmisation is a must, as blocking states, in principal, could and will devastate all benefits a parallel code-execution may provide.

For details, read about [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel)  **[Synchronisation Variables](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelSyncvar.html)**.

---

### Epilogue

In any case, **a design, that has to resort to block** ( using any kind of  a barrier, or waiting for a synchronisation variable, or expecting a message from a CSP-channel et al ) **ought be the very last option**, if all other Computer Science tools and refactoring efforts have failed to provide any better, and as much `PAR` as possible, algorithmisation. Besides the blocking, per-se, [the **Amdahl Law** ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) goes steeply down, back to a performance of a pure `SEQ` schedule.

Serious HPC is not based on using wait-states, but the very opposite.